# Output only the date component of a date + time in Grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy, kendo-ui

In grails, If I use `dateCreated()` instance in domain class then it returns date + time stamp.
If I have to remove time stamp and retrieve only date on view page then is there any method to perform such task without modifying in domain class And also I have grid in my view page in which its showing date+time stamp so I also want to remove time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [formatDate tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatDate.html).

Comment: Thanx fr replying @FlareCoder,

Comment: But i don't want to make changes in my domain class. So is there any more method so that i can implement in my _gridOrDetail.gsp?

Answer (score 6):

You can just format that date to show what you want. [Docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.1/ref/Tags/formatDate.html)

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${date}"/>
```

Comment: @AnujChaurasia No problem, if its working for you don't forget to mark as correct.